# Short riddle, inspired by a word #2

Tags: riddle, word

```
Not an ocean nor the sun, 
Something you are when you've just begun.
Don't eat me as I am even though you can.
A party that few seeks, be careful of the freaks.

Shares shade with a viper
And though woods hold a tiger,
In a desert you’d oft not see.
Can you guess what word inspired me?
```

This one should be less ambiguous than my previous attempt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it

> Green

Not an ocean nor the sun

> on maps, land is often shown as green where ocean is blue. The sun is yellow

Something you are when you've just begun

> someone new at something is often referred to as 'green'

Don't eat me as I am even though you can

> Many green fruits aren't ripe yet, you need to wait to eat them later.

A party that few seeks, be careful of the freaks.

> could be referencing the rather unpopular green party in US politics (@kayzeroshort)

Shares shade with a viper

> poison is often colored green in cartoons and such

And though woods hold a tiger

> woods are green, but a tiger's stripes work to camoflage it without the green color because it mimics patterns of light and shadow, as opposed to color.
>  Edit: Tiger Woods plays golf on a putting 'green' (@kayzeroshort)

In a desert you'd oft not see.

> Not much green in a desert!

Can you guess what word inspired me?

> Green!

Comment: Nice. Other clues might be related to an American political party and the athlete Tiger Woods.

Comment: Also, a more explicit viper connection: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mamba#Species

Comment: Right on! Good job on deciphering most of the lines @kayzeroshort You were right with your comments as well. Was thinking of green vipers, and shade is a play on word for the colors.